# How to draw ng2-charts horizontal bar chart with custom scales in Angular?

Tags: angular, bar-chart, ng2-charts

I am trying a horizontal bar chart with ng2-charts as below to draw with custom scale i.e.

[image: Desired-Output]

This is what I have achieved so far  where I am getting output as  [image: Actual-Output]

**Code:**

```
  public barChartColors: any [] =[
    {
      backgroundColor:'#5081bd',
    },
    {
      backgroundColor:'rgba(80,129,189,255)',
    }
];

  public barChartOptions1: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
       {
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
         display: true,
         labelString: "",
         fontSize: 20
        },
       },
      ]
    }
  }



public barChartType1: ChartType = "horizontalBar";

DesignHorizantalBarChart(chartdata: any) {
    
    let dataobj = {};
    let setData = [];
    let setLabels = [];
    let arr = [];
    chartdata.forEach((element, index) => {

      element.index = index;

      if (!element.isOpenText) {
        setLabels = [...element.responses];
        let average = ((element.average * element.responses.length) / 100);


        setData.push(average.toFixed(2));
        
        dataobj = {
          data: setData,
          label: element.reportTitle,
          stack: element.reportTitle,
        };

        arr.push(dataobj);
        this.barChartDataSets1.push(arr);
        this.barChartLabels1.push(setLabels);

        arr = [];
        setData = [];
        setLabels = [];
      }
    });

  }
```

**Input JSON data from function parameters:**

```
[
   {
      "guid":"bb3cbb02-c0e7-440c-bd44-5c2bc25a249c",
      "questionTitle":"Custom Question 2",
      "reportTitle":"first report",
      "responses":[
         "ans1",
         "ans2"
      ],
      "openText":[
         
      ],
      "isOpenText":false,
      "result":null,
      "average":66.66666666666666,
      "sampleSize":3
   }
]
```

**Input Feed for chart after preparing data:**

```
barChartDataSets1 [[{"data":["1.33"],"label":"first report","stack":"first report"}]]
generate-report.component.ts:290 barChartLabels1 [["ans1","ans2"]]
```

**Template:**

```
                    <canvas baseChart  height="20vh" width="80vw"
                        [colors]="barChartColors" 
                        [datasets]="barChartDataSets1[customdata.index]"
                        [labels]="barChartLabels1[customdata.index]" 
                        [options]="barChartOptions1" 
                        [chartType]="barChartType1" 
                        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" 
                        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
                    </canvas>
```

I would like to flip the scales and shown in desired output image without flipping the data or something like that. How this can be achieved? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this will do the job:

```
public barChartOptions1: ChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
    x: {
      min: 0,
      max: 4
    }
  }
}
```

Also You can set only one of them and on both `x` axes and `y` axes.

Comment: I will test it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more with using the above inputs. I am not able to understand it.

Comment: By providing `x` like above, i am getting error stating that `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'x' does not exist in type 'ChartScales | LinearScale | LogarithmicScale | TimeScale'.ts(2322)`. I tried to change it to `xAxes` which removed the error for `x` but gives error on `min` stating that i does not exists on `xAxes` object.

Comment: try with `xAxes`.

Comment: Tried that as well but it states `min` does not exists on `xAxes`.

Comment: what is your chart.js version?

Comment: These are the imports that I am currently using for the above chart.
`import { SingleDataSet, Label } from "ng2-charts";`
`import { ChartType, ChartOptions } from "chart.js";`

Versions are as under in package.json
`"chart.js": "^2.8.0",`
`"ng2-charts": "^2.3.0"`

Comment: to use `min` and `max` you need `^3.0.0`. can you migrate?

Comment: which one to upgrade ? chart.js or ng2-charts ?

Comment: both. upgrade your chart.js and ng2-charts to the latest version.

Comment: If you want to see the success result, go to https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/linear-min-max.html and https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/vertical.html and play with the charts with `min` and `max`.

Comment: ok. i am updating versions. will definitely check above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239976/discussion-between-ahsan-and-skyblue).

Answer (score -1):

As bar chart was not able to cater the problem so I stumbled upon this solution where I have changed the chart type from `horizontalBar` chart to `line` chart.

```
public lineChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    legend: { display: false },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
       {
        display: false,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: '',
          fontSize: 20,
         }
       },
      ]
    
    },
    
    elements: {
      point:{
          radius: 0,
          borderWidth: 50
      }
    },
  };
```

This solved my problem.